# World Cup Java Code ( Creating a User Input Which Prompts the User when to Begin a Round)

Tags: java, function, class

I am trying to create a class which allows to provide user input using a 'char' to allow the user of the program to being each round of a Round 16 World Cup. I am stump as I've been trying to create it on a separate class file and then call it to the Main Class whenever it is needed.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WorldCupMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the FIFA 2023 World Cup");
        System.out.println("Teams that will be facing off in Group A, Group B, Group C & Group D" + "\n" + "\n" + "Group A:");
        Teams GroupA = new Teams();
        GroupA.addTeam("Argentina");
        GroupA.addTeam("Portugal");
        GroupA.addTeam("England");
        GroupA.addTeam("Germany");
        ArrayList<String> teams = GroupA.getList();
        System.out.println(teams.get(3) + " " + " vs." + " " + teams.get(0) + "\n");
        System.out.println(teams.get(2) + " " + " vs." + " " + teams.get(1) + "\n");
        System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////////////");
        System.out.println("Group B:");
        Teams GroupB = new Teams();
        GroupB.addTeam("United States");
        GroupB.addTeam("France");
        GroupB.addTeam("Spain");
        GroupB.addTeam("Japan");
        ArrayList<String> teams2 = GroupB.getList();
        System.out.println(teams2.get(3) + " " + " vs." + " " + teams2.get(0) + "\n");
        System.out.println(teams2.get(2) + " " + " vs." + " " + teams2.get(1) + "\n");
        System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////////////");
        System.out.println("Group C:");
        Teams GroupC = new Teams();
        GroupC.addTeam("Canada");
        GroupC.addTeam("Mexico");
        GroupC.addTeam("Poland");
        GroupC.addTeam("South Korea");
        ArrayList<String> teams3 = GroupC.getList();
        System.out.println(teams3.get(3) + " " + " vs." + " " + teams3.get(0) + "\n");
        System.out.println(teams3.get(2) + " " + " vs." + " " + teams3.get(1) + "\n");
        System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////////////");
        System.out.println("Group D:");
        Teams GroupD = new Teams();
        GroupD.addTeam("Uruguay");
        GroupD.addTeam("Wales");
        GroupD.addTeam("Switzerland");
        GroupD.addTeam("Croatia");
        ArrayList<String> teams4 = GroupD.getList();
        System.out.println(teams4.get(3) + " " + " vs." + " " + teams4.get(0) + "\n");
        System.out.println(teams4.get(2) + " " + " vs." + " " + teams4.get(1) + "\n");
        System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////////////");
    }
}
```

Teams.java on a separate class file.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Teams {
    /* GROUP A */
    ArrayList<String> groupA;

    public Teams() {
        groupA = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addTeam(String team) {
        groupA.add(team);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getList() {
        return groupA;
    }
}
```

I have been trying to get it to work but I am not quite sure how to. Please any suggestion on what I could do to create a class to perform as a function rather placing it inside of the Main class directly.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want your program to do. What `char` is the user supposed to enter? What do you want the program to do after the user enters this `char`?

Comment: Like the letter 's' or 'S' and the program would begin the round  for each match

Comment: Do you know how to write Java code that gets a `char` entered by the user?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the FIFA 2023 World Cup");
        System.out.println("Teams that will be facing off in Group A, Group B, Group C & Group D" + "\n");
        Teams.print("A");
        Teams.print("B");
        Teams.print("C");
        Teams.print("D");
    }
}
```

Teams.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Teams {

    private static List<String> getGroup(String groupName) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if ("A".equals(groupName)) {
            list.add("Argentina");
            list.add("Portugal");
            list.add("England");
            list.add("Germany");
        } else if ("B".equals(groupName)) {
            list.add("United States");
            list.add("France");
            list.add("Spain");
            list.add("Japan");
        } else if ("C".equals(groupName)) {
            list.add("Canada");
            list.add("Mexico");
            list.add("Poland");
            list.add("South Korea");
        } else {
            list.add("Uruguay");
            list.add("Wales");
            list.add("Switzerland");
            list.add("Croatia");
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void print(String groupName) {
        List<String> teams = getGroup(groupName);
        System.out.println("Group " + groupName + ":");
        System.out.println(teams.get(3) + " " + " vs." + " " + teams.get(0) + "\n");
        System.out.println(teams.get(2) + " " + " vs." + " " + teams.get(1) + "\n");
        System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////////////");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the helping me with my code, it was very insightful I made I am not finished but I made some progress thanks to the help